# Identification of Connector

Tags: connector, identification, cables

I need to identify a connector on this image. It is the one labeled as 'Input Cable'. Image is from https://www.alphaomega-eng.com/neurofortis.html. [image]

This is how the corresponding cable looks like (black connector). Unfortunately this is the only image available (to me) since I do not have the cable at my disposal to take any images myself:

[image]

Comment: Well, you did take photos of everything, except the connector.

Comment: Unfortunately the image of the cable was given to me, otherwise I would have taken more images from more angles to simplify the identification process.

Comment: Seeing as the image came from the [product page](https://www.alphaomega-eng.com/neurofortis.html), perhaps the cable image came from another page on the same site.

Comment: This is indeed a good idea, I already checked the product page. Unfortunately I was neither able to find the cable itself nor any technical information on the headstage regarding the cable. But I'll add the link to the website with the headstage image to the answer.

Comment: On a medical device, connectors are likely to be proprietary (custom-made) for the customer.